# Struts Action HTTP 500

Tags: java, struts-1

I have this action:

```
<action path="/view.stif.loader.bin.mapping" 
type="com.st.mas.wmr.action.StifBinConversionAction" parameter="viewLoaderMapping" 
name="stifConvForm" scope="request" validate="false" 
input=".editConfig">
<forward name="success" path=".viewStifLoadBinMapping"/>
</action>
```

This action used to work, but now it doesn't and I don't know why. I get `HTTP Status 500 - No action instance for path /view.stif.loader.bin.mapping could be created`. The Action class is still there, and no change is done to `struts-config.xml`.

What other reasons could cause HTTP 500?

I'm using Struts 1 with Tiles.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Http 500 indicates that something is wrong on the server side.

In your case, you could try the following 
1. Verify the action class exists with the right package path. This is to be checked in the appropriate container (i.e. tomcat, weblogic, jboss, etc)
2. Check if its working by replacing the current action by an already working action. If yes, then there is something wrong with the action
3. try clean build to get a freshly compiled class files. Sometimes, this solves the problem